# React Native 0.72.4 'ReactCommon/TurboModule.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

With React Native 0.72.4, building iOS in Xcode I got an error

```
'ReactCommon/TurboModule.h' file not found
```

I've tried

```
  post_install do |installer|
    ...
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if ["React-NativeModulesApple"].any? { |t| t == target.name }
        append_header_search_path(target, "${PODS_ROOT}/../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon")
      end
    end
  end
```

according to https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/issues/2081#issuecomment-1691758876
but it didn't work.